# Is it possible to visually view the differences (changes) of text files while copying them with Caja?

Tags: files, mate, diff, caja

I have two files with the same name in two different folders.

I need to copy the text file from source to destination. Usually I use Caja's *Extra Pane* (accessible by <kbd>F3</kbd>) for doing so:

[image: Caja with opened Extra Pane]

I remembered nice feature - viewing differences of the files visually exists in Caja.
I have this option on one machine, but does not have it on other.

Which application should I install to get the comparison (*Differences*) option

[image: Caja's Replace dialog with Differences button]

in *File Conflict* (replace file) dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependencies of Caja shows that along with other packages it suggests to install [Meld visual diff tool](http://meldmerge.org/):

> ```
> $ apt-cache depends caja
>   ...
>   Suggests: meld
> ```

So to get this great and useful feature we need to install Meld package with:

```
sudo apt-get install meld
```

and compare the file contents easily in Meld by clicking on *Differences* button:

[image: Meld is opened after click on Differences button]

And it is great that this functionality exists in all current Ubuntu MATE versions - 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS and 19.04.